# Convert spark dataframe with collect_list(column) back to long format

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Say we have the dataframe iris:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uiuc-cse/data-fa14/gh-pages/data/iris.csv')
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

I need to perform some aggregate function on sepal width by species, like getting the 3 highest values per group.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
get_max_3 = F.udf(
    lambda x: sorted(x)[-3:]
)

agged = df.groupBy('species').agg(F.collect_list('sepal_width').alias('sepal_width'))
agged = agged.withColumn('sepal_width', get_max_3('sepal_width'))

+----------+---------------+
|   species|    sepal_width|
+----------+---------------+
| virginica|[3.6, 3.8, 3.8]|
|versicolor|[3.2, 3.3, 3.4]|
|    setosa|[4.1, 4.2, 4.4]|
+----------+---------------+
```

Now, how would I efficiently turn this back into a dataframe in the long format (meaning three rows for each of the species, with each row corresponding to one value)?

And is there a way to do this without using `collect_list`?

Answer (score 5):

To convert data frame back to long format, you can use `explode`; To use this method, however you need to fix your `udf` firstly, so it returns the correct type:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

get_max_3 = F.udf(lambda x: sorted(x)[-3:], ArrayType(DoubleType()))

agged = agged.withColumn('sepal_width', get_max_3('sepal_width'))
agged.withColumn('sepal_width', F.explode(F.col('sepal_width'))).show()

+----------+-----------+
|   species|sepal_width|
+----------+-----------+
| virginica|        3.6|
| virginica|        3.8|
| virginica|        3.8|
|versicolor|        3.2|
|versicolor|        3.3|
|versicolor|        3.4|
|    setosa|        4.1|
|    setosa|        4.2|
|    setosa|        4.4|
+----------+-----------+
```

---

Or without collecting as a list and explode, you can rank the `sepal_width` column firstly and then filter based on the `rank`:

```
df.selectExpr(
    "species", "sepal_width", 
    "row_number() over (partition by species order by sepal_width desc) as rn"
).where(F.col("rn") <= 3).drop("rn").show()
+----------+-----------+
|   species|sepal_width|
+----------+-----------+
| virginica|        3.8|
| virginica|        3.8|
| virginica|        3.6|
|versicolor|        3.4|
|versicolor|        3.3|
|versicolor|        3.2|
|    setosa|        4.4|
|    setosa|        4.2|
|    setosa|        4.1|
+----------+-----------+
```